# FileIO.AppendTextAsync is actually overwriting

Tags: c#, file-io, uwp

I'm using `FileIO` to append Json data in a `LocalStorage` file.

```cs
public static async Task AppendToJsonLocalStorage<T>(string filename, T objectToWrite) where T : new()
{
    StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    StorageFile saveFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    var contentsToWriteToFile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToWrite);
    await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(saveFile, contentsToWriteToFile);
}
```

`AppendTextAsync` should only add new text at the end of the existing file, wright ?

Because when I check the file in my file explorer with a text editor it's always overwriting the former text in it.

Comment: Well you are using `CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting` which will replace the existing file.

Comment: The joy of copy / pasting ....

Comment: Never, ever, copy paste code without understanding what it is doing, I'm afraid this is entirely your fault.

Comment: Sure, you're wright. I wrote a similar function that was supposed to replace the file before, so I just copy / pasted it to make a new one supposed to append and apparently I forgot about some parameters..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists` instead of `CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting` when you create the file:

```
StorageFile saveFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
var contentsToWriteToFile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToWrite);
await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(saveFile, contentsToWriteToFile);
```

`ReplaceExisting` replaces any existing file as the name suggests. Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.creationcollisionoption) for more information.

Comment: Exactly. OP's code doesn't actually _overwrite_, it discards and recreates.